# Import an Existing Database with Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, import

I have a situation with a program in Java; it works with Databases.

I want to know if is possible to import a Database which dump file is stored within the source files of my project.

I don't want to use an absolute path to the file like:

`C:\PATH\FILE.SQL`

Instead I would like to use somthing like:

`\FILE.SQL`

In my project I use this line of code to import the dump file, that works fine but using an absolute PATH.

`String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql", "--user=root", "--password=" + psw, "control_schema", "-e", "C:/DataBase/DataBase.sql"};`

Since I don't want this absolute PATH `C:/DataBase/DataBase.sql`, I want some help from you.

Is possible to use a relative PATH like `/DataBase/DataBase.sql` to import the dump file which is stored within my src project folder?

Comment: well if you are in the folder you get rid of the entire path. Is this sql file in your classpath?

Comment: The dump file is stored in a source package called DATABASE, I have others source packages that works well with images, I use that for background images for the panel containers, the jdesktop panes, etc, but the line code I posted above, doesn't works. What can I do?

Comment: The line code works well with an absolute PATH, but does not with a relative one, am I doing rigth or this way to code that is wrong?

Comment: You did not answer my question: Is the file on your classpath?

Comment: So assuming it is in the package `database` you should be able to access it programatically at runtime with `database/file.sql`